# Is there any reason I shouldn't make pages folderish

Tags: plone

I find the hardest thing to explain to Plone end users is the concept of having to make a folder, a page and set the folder's default view to a page in order to have nested pages. Is there any reason I shouldn't include a folderish version of a page content type in my product?

Comment: I can't think of an example of a page that doesn't have images on it... from a users perspective a folder, with a page configured to be the the default view is more complex than folder considering all the complexity of a folder is included in this arrangement, plus more.

Comment: Versioning and history of folders are a bit more challenging if you need it to extend to the content as well, so I personally would look into automating "create folder, create your content type object in it and set it as default page" into something userfriendly.

Comment: Can you recommend a resource for learning how to automate this process?

Comment: there are [events that are fired when an object is created](http://developer.plone.org/components/events.html#creation-events), you would probably want to subscribe to those events and then do something with the new object, i.e. create the subobjects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are existing products that provide folderish types that almost behave like pages for the end-user

eg. Products.Richdocument and raptus.article.

personally i prefere raptus.article because of it's concept of components. editors can activate carousels, or image galleries and define which of the contained images are displayed in which component.
in many project i also define custom components eg one for showing addthis integration under the article text if editors turn on the component.

Ulrich Schwarz is right when commenting that using folderish content types as pages brings in extra complexity when it comes to versioning.
the problems in versioning with cmfeditions could most likle be solved by using attributestorage instead of annotationstorage for archetypes fields. (see https://dev.plone.org/ticket/11887)

Comment: Can you please provide a link for Products.Richtdocument?

Comment: sorry, i had a typo in the package name: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.RichDocument

Comment: When you say there are problems with versioning, does that mean the History link on a rich text field on a folderish type won't work?

Comment: the history will show who edited when and also the workflow transitions as usual. but cmfedition's diff tool won't be able to show diffs for fields using annotationstorage since this storage is excluded for folderish types

Answer (score 0):

The simplest was is to compare Plone as a filesystem.

There are discussions/rumors about making all content types folderish, but right now I suggest you to to something folderish only when really needed. The UI of a folderish content is more complex

Answer (score 0):

Keul is right. Compare Plone as a filesystem.

I think also that you don't always have to set a page as the default view of a folder, sometimes you just want to have a list of contents (files, images, pages, etc...).

Comment: Although the suggestion is to make pages folderish not- folders pagish... there could still be folders.