# How do I set a one to one relationship between a folder and a dexterity content type?

Tags: plone, dexterity

I have a dexterity content type and I would like there to only ever be one of these in a folder. I cannot find any documentation to cover this. How is it accomplished?

Comment: The obvious answer is to incorporate the fields for this singleton into the folder content type. Why not?

Comment: Any progress/more questions?

Comment: @SteveM: To answer your question: It would change the tree-structure completely. Hoewever, if the singleton-contentype is supposed to be the default_view of it's container anyway, your suggestion would apply. And it's a very good question, heavily discussed on the lists ('default-view-story'). Personally I can see no obstacles to do it, and am using folderish-contentypes very often. Just some minor tweaks needed, as e.g. for enableling versioning (a.k.a. contentobject-history).

Comment: It's not for the default view, though I did ask about that before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21136538/is-there-any-reason-i-shouldnt-make-pages-folderish?noredirect=1#comment31852325_21136538 I think this is a good suggestion, SteveM.

Comment: Is there documentation for adding a field to the default folder type? (There is already a lot of "folder" content in the site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an event-listener, which applies on creation of your type and removes your type of the addable-types of its parent, like described in:

https://developer.plone.org/content/types.html#constraining-the-addable-types-per-type-instance

Consequently you probably also want to redo the setting when deleting this contenttype, by adding another event-listener for the deletion.